# Nominalization for "to address"

Tags: single-word-requests, nominalizations

is there a nominalization of the verb "to address"?

As in "They have addressed the issue in a recent statement. What is their ____ ?"

Thanks

Comment: Hi Josh- how does "focus" fit into the blank? I don't think it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: To address here means to direct attention to ( a matter). What do you mean to ask in ? What is their....?

Comment: Nominalization = noun form?

Answer (score 4):

How about **addressal**?

Here's the [Webster's definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addressal):

> the act of addressing something (such as a problem or issue)

I must add that this does not seem to be a very common word.

Comment: +1 Common enough for me to believe. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=addressal&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caddressal%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @ScotM - Look again at your ngram. Even the peak value for the prevalence of 'addressal' attains only 0.00000018%. This cannot, by any reasonable measure, be described as signifying 'common'.

Comment: Agreed. I'm coloring outside the lines, because Uncle Sam and Merriam-Webster say it's OK.